# Linux filter/sort input using awk

Tags: linux, awk

Looking for subtitle track that has `default_track:1` (if any), and output the Track ID. In this case the output should be `2`

So far I have this:

```
awk '/: subtitles.*default_track:1/ {gsub(".*Track ID ", "", $0); gsub(" .*", "", $0); print $0 }'
```

Which gives me this:

```
2:
```

But I'm looking for this:

```
2
```

Here is the input:

```
File 'v.mkv': container: Matroska [duration:71255000000 segment_uid:833ce3259a9891d7030fd4c31dd10a32 is_providing_timecodes:1]
Track ID 0: video (DIV3) [number:1 uid:1568461043394572035 codec_id:V_MS/VFW/FOURCC codec_private_length:40 codec_private_data:280000008002000060010000010018004449563300500a0000000000000000000000000000000000 language:und pixel_dimensions:640x352 display_dimensions:640x352 default_track:1 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 default_duration:41708375 tag_bps:1278655 tag_duration:00\c01\c09.778000000 tag_number_of_frames:1673 tag_number_of_bytes:11152757 tag__statistics_writing_app:mkvmerge\sv7.3.0\s('Nouages')\s64bit\sbuilt\son\sNov\s30\s2014\s09\c21\c17 tag__statistics_writing_date_utc:2014-11-30\s08\c22\c46 tag__statistics_tags:BPS\sDURATION\sNUMBER_OF_FRAMES\sNUMBER_OF_BYTES]
Track ID 1: audio (MP3) [number:2 uid:15602440298129597552 codec_id:A_MPEG/L3 codec_private_length:0 language:und default_track:1 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 default_duration:24000000 audio_sampling_frequency:48000 audio_channels:2 tag_bps:224451 tag_duration:00\c01\c09.768000000 tag_number_of_frames:2907 tag_number_of_bytes:1957440 tag__statistics_writing_app:mkvmerge\sv7.3.0\s('Nouages')\s64bit\sbuilt\son\sNov\s30\s2014\s09\c21\c17 tag__statistics_writing_date_utc:2014-11-30\s08\c22\c46 tag__statistics_tags:BPS\sDURATION\sNUMBER_OF_FRAMES\sNUMBER_OF_BYTES]
Track ID 2: subtitles (SubRip/SRT) [number:3 uid:7565148441499248899 codec_id:S_TEXT/UTF8 codec_private_length:0 language:und default_track:1 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 tag_bps:79 tag_duration:00\c01\c06.555000000 tag_number_of_frames:18 tag_number_of_bytes:664 tag__statistics_writing_app:mkvmerge\sv7.3.0\s('Nouages')\s64bit\sbuilt\son\sNov\s30\s2014\s09\c21\c17 tag__statistics_writing_date_utc:2014-11-30\s08\c22\c46 tag__statistics_tags:BPS\sDURATION\sNUMBER_OF_FRAMES\sNUMBER_OF_BYTES]
Track ID 3: subtitles (SubRip/SRT) [number:4 uid:10370072232421497499 codec_id:S_TEXT/UTF8 codec_private_length:0 language:und default_track:0 forced_track:0 enabled_track:1 tag_bps:70 tag_duration:00\c01\c06.555000000 tag_number_of_frames:18 tag_number_of_bytes:590 tag__statistics_writing_app:mkvmerge\sv7.3.0\s('Nouages')\s64bit\sbuilt\son\sNov\s30\s2014\s09\c21\c17 tag__statistics_writing_date_utc:2014-11-30\s08\c22\c46 tag__statistics_tags:BPS\sDURATION\sNUMBER_OF_FRAMES\sNUMBER_OF_BYTES]
…
```

Comment: add one more `sub(/:/, "", $0)` ? Good luck.

Comment: `awk '/: subtitles.*default_track:1/ {gsub(":", "", $3); print $3}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
awk -F'[ :]+' '$4=="subtitles"&&/default_track:1[[:space:]]/{print $3}' yourfile
```

It sets the field separator to also have `:` included.

The PATTERN-part checks two things: If the fourth field equals subtitles, and if `default_track:1` is somewhere in the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' '/subtitles.*default_track:1/{print $3}' file
2
```

If there can be other strings in your file that contain `subtitles` or `default_track:1` then surround them with word boundaries, e.g. with GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F'[ :]' '/\<subtitles\>.*\<default_track:1\>/{print $3}' file
2
```

Answer (score 0):

A small `+` fixes your problem:

```
awk '/: subtitles.*default_track:1/ {print +$3}' file
2
```

Using `+` it will add `0` to `2:`.  This will get the value only.